# Why the is the set operator "includes" equivalent to the logical operator "implies"?

Tags: logic, notation

Let's say we have a superset called "People" (P). In that superset we have two subsets, "Men" (M) and "Women" (W). We can say that:

$P  \supset M$

$P  \supset W$

In logical language, this is equivalent to:

1. $P   \Rightarrow  M$
2. $P   \Rightarrow  W$

But translated to human language, (1) means that being a Person implies being a Man, and (2) means that being a Person implies being a Woman, which does not make any logical sense.

Shouldn't the equivalence between sets and logic be the other way round?

1. $P   \Leftarrow  M$
2. $P   \Leftarrow  W$

Now, being a man, obviously implies being a Person, and being a woman obviously 
 implies being a Person.

Comment: Yes, the logical symbol $\supset$ for $\implies$ is indeed confusing, and I guess, even its origin is probably *independent* from the set theoretic symbol $\subseteq$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $M \subset H$, that reads : the set of Males is a subset of the set of Humans", is **defined** by the formula :

> $\forall x (\text Mx \to \text H (x))$,

that reads : "every Male is Human".

The relationship between the symbol $\subset$ for set *inclusion* and $\supset$ for the *conditional* connective ("if…, then…") is historical; see the post [Why is there this strange contradiction between the language of logic and that of set theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106001/why-is-there-this-strange-contradiction-between-the-language-of-logic-and-that-o) as well as the post [Is there any connection between the symbol $\supset$ when it means implication and its meaning as superset?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146443/is-there-any-connection-between-the-symbol-supset-when-it-means-implication-a)

In a nutshell :

> [Ernst Schröder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Schr%C3%B6der), into *Vorlesungen uber die Algebra der Logik*, Vol. I (Leipzig, 1890), used $\subset$ for "is included in" (*untergeordnet*) and $\supset$ for "includes" (*ubergeordnet*).
>
> [Giuseppe Peano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Peano) expressed the relations and operations of logic in Volume I of his *Formulaire de mathematiques* (1895) by the signs $\in$, **c**, **ɔ**, [...] the meanings of which are, respectively, "is" (i.e., is a member of), "contains," "is contained in," [...].

Peano "inverted c" becomes $\supset$ :

> On pourrait indiquer la relation $p \supset q$ par le signe $q \text C p$ qu'on lira "$q$ est conséquence de $p$".

The diffusion of the use of $\supset$ to deonte the *conditional* is due to Whitehead & Russell's [Principia Mathematica (1910-1913)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/).